# Text join code in Excel returns Zeros instead skipping blank cells

Tags: excel

I’m using Excel Version 2008 and I would like my spreadsheet to populate a list with all the items that have a score below 34. Here’s my code:

`=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(Points!$D$3:$D$17<38,Points!$C$3:$C$17,""))`

When I run the above in my spreadsheet I get all of the items that qualify, but I also get a ZERO for each blank cell in the range. I have a similar formula for scored items above 38:

`=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(Points!$D$3:$D$16>=38,Points!$C$3:$C$16,""))`

This one works just fine. It returns just the names and no ZEROS. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is that Excel 2008 for Mac? Or do you mean Excel for Office 365, build 2008 (As in 2020 - August release)

Comment: Every formula that references an empty cell will return a zero. That is expected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Zero is returned because the formula that is referenced is empty. Check if the result range is empty, like this:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(A1:A10<38,IF(B1:B10="","",B1:B10),""))
```

[image]

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.